# PHP Validation of date format using regex

Tags: php

When a user enters a date in text box,i've to check ,whether it is in yyyy-mm-dd format.

**Note** Even month,date,for eg:2012-02-32 is not valid because,date can be only till 31 and same for month,he can n't enter month as 13.

If it is in wrong format,i should echo.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$e = explode('-', '2012-02-32');
if (checkdate($e[1], $e[2], $e[0])){
    // Valid
}else{
    // Invalid
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
list($year,$month,$day) = explode('-', $input);
if (checkdate($month, $day, $year)) {
    // Correct
} else {
    // Incorrect
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading comments on http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php is quite informative, including validating through regexp.

I use the following code from that page:

```
function checkDateTime($data) {
    if (date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data)) == $data) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also I'd recommend adding JavaScript datepicker http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

that's exactly what you need: http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Answer (score 0):

You should not use regular expressions for this. A better (maybe not the best) is to use [checkdate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php);

```
$parts = explode('-', $input);
if (sizeof($parts) == 3 && checkdate($parts[1], $parts[2], $parts[0])) {
    // Correct
} else {
    // Incorrect
}
```

Comment: :error on line 2Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND